# How to subtract one array from another, element-wise, in javascript

Tags: javascript

If i have an array `A = [1, 4, 3, 2]` and `B = [0, 2, 1, 2]` I want to return a new array (A - B) with values `[1, 2, 2, 0]`. What is the most efficient approach to do this in javascript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the fastest or most elegant way to compute a set difference using Javascript arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723168/what-is-the-fastest-or-most-elegant-way-to-compute-a-set-difference-using-javasc)

Comment: A user with your rep should know the importance of sharing effort in question. SO is to get help for your problems and not solution for your requirements

Comment: Try this.,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187518/javascript-array-difference

Comment: Try this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187518/javascript-array-difference

Comment: The caluclated values in the example are wrong. It should be [1,2,2,0] and not [0,2,2,0].

Answer (score 132):

If you want to find the *set difference* between two sets, that is, you want all the elements of A that are not in B:

```js
const A = [1, 4, 3, 2]
const B = [0, 2, 1, 2]
console.log(A.filter(n => !B.includes(n)))
```

If you want arithmetic differences between the elements of A and the corresponding elements of B, then please look to the other posted answers.

Comment: explanations would be helpful!

Comment: @platinums the solution just filters the array A and returns an array containing all the elements from the array A that are not included in B, effectively subtracting B from A.

Comment: This is NOT what rrbest is asking for.

Comment: @danger89, agree with you, as a simple solution for this (*in case both arrays have the same length*):

`ArrA.map((n, i) => n - ArrB[i]);`

Comment: By searching for "subtract array" I actually was looking for this answer, lol. Thanks

Comment: It may not be what the original question was asking for, but it sure is what most people landing here from google are asking for, judging by the relative upvotes.

Answer (score 47):

Use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method
The map method takes three parameters in it's callback function  like below

```
currentValue, index, array
```

```js
var a = [1, 4, 3, 2],
  b = [0, 2, 1, 2]

var x = a.map(function(item, index) {
  // In this case item correspond to currentValue of array a, 
  // using index to get value from array b
  return item - b[index];
})
console.log(x);
```

Comment: es6 version:

var x = a.map((item, index) => item - b[index])

Answer (score 8):

`For` Simple and efficient ever.

Check here : [`JsPref - For Vs Map Vs forEach`](https://jsperf.com/forloop-vs-mapbysank/1)

```js
var a = [1, 4, 3, 2],
  b = [0, 2, 1, 2],
  x = [];

for(var i = 0;i<=b.length-1;i++)
  x.push(a[i] - b[i]);
  
console.log(x);
```

Comment: Both arrays length, suppose to be same. otherwise it can create a problem. Or handle it before.

Comment: @AvneshShakya Yes. Both array should be same and that's what asked.

Comment: Strange, for me the JsPerf above doesn't show the for loop as fastest. So I made my own: https://jsperf.com/for-loop-vs-map-vs-for-each-kce and found that for large n the for loop is many times faster.

Answer (score 3):

```
const A = [1, 4, 3, 2]
const B = [0, 2, 1, 2]
const C = A.map((valueA, indexInA) => valueA - B[indexInA])
console.log(C) // [1, 2, 2, 0]
```

Here the `map` is returning the substraction operation for each number of the first array.

**Note:** this will not work if the arrays have different lengths

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

One-liner using ES6 for the array's of equal size in length:

```
 let subResult = a.map((v, i) => v - b[i]); // [1, 2, 2, 0]
```

v = value, i = index

Answer (score 1):

If you want to override values in the first table you can simply use forEach method for arrays [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). ForEach method takes the same parameter as map method (element, index, array). It's similar with the previous answer with map keyword but here we are not returning the value but assign value by own.

```js
var a = [1, 4, 3, 2],
  b = [0, 2, 1, 2]
  
a.forEach(function(item, index, arr) {
  // item - current value in the loop
  // index - index for this value in the array
  // arr - reference to analyzed array  
  arr[index] = item - b[index];
})

//in this case we override values in first array
console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function subtract(operand1 = [], operand2 = []) {
console.log('array1', operand1, 'array2', operand2);
const obj1 = {};

if (operand1.length === operand2.length) {
    return operand1.map(($op, i) => {
        return $op - operand2[i];
    })
}
throw new Error('collections are of different lengths');
}

// Test by generating a random array
function getRandomArray(total){
const pool = []
for (let i = 0; i < total; i++) {
    pool.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * total));
}

return pool;
}
console.log(subtract(getRandomArray(10), getRandomArray(10)))
```

Time Complexity is `O(n)`
You can also compare your answer with a big collection of arrays.